# Load website name from ruby configuration file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to externalize the name of the application to a config file. In Zend, you can define these parameters in the config.ini [production] and inherit this in all environments.

So is there a way of storing this in a single config file and have it inherited in all environments, say a yml file for instance. I am really new to ROR, so I understand this might be a obvious questio, just that I didn't find too much on a google search

Comment: http://railscasts.com/episodes/85-yaml-configuration-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my project, I put a settings.yml file under the app's config folder

```
default: &default
  domain_www: www.abc.com
  some_setting_value: 123

development:
  <<: *default
  domain_www: www.test.com

production:
  <<: *default
  domain_www: www.inproduction.com
```

And create a load_settings.rb in your app's config/initializers folder

`SETTINGS = YAML.load_file("#{Rails.root}/config/settings.yml")[Rails.env]`

Since Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers and all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.